# How to fix MySql server in wamp that is not able to display the table with INNODB engines?

Tags: mysql

MySql server can display all the tables with MyISAM engines but cannot able to display the tables with INNODB engines, but if I can make the tables with INNODB engines it can still show that tables, but it is unable to show already made tables with INNODB engines?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your `.err` log, as it's most likely some type of table space corruption.

The location of the log file is specified via two methods. The first is at run time with `--log-error=filename`, which would often be specified in your init file. More commonly, it would be specified in your my.cnf with `log-error`. Ultimately if left unset, it defaults to the data directory as your `hostname.err`.

Search the filesystem for a file with the extension of `.err`. Chances are, you'll find the log.

```
find / -name '*.err'
locate .err | egrep '.err$'
```